# How do I flush right page numbers in Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

In the LaTeX template that I am using (ArsClassica),  the Table of Contents has page numbers next to section names.

Could anyone tell me how I could make these numbers  flush right?

I would also like to how to add '...' between section names and the page numbers.

Comment: The normal behaviour of ToC page number is to be right aligned. As long as you don't post a compilable example, there is not much to help you, however...

Comment: What you are after is the normal ToC layout in the standard LaTeX classes, so your template (whatever it is as you don't tell us) alters that. By any chance does it call for the `tocloft` package which is one way of changing the default layout? If it does then comment out any of its changes referring to sections. To read the manual `texdoc tocloft`.

Comment: Hi, thank everyone who responds to my post. I use a thesis template called ArsClassica. https://ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica?lang=en

Comment: The `arsclassica` package depends on the `classicthesis` package which uses `tocloft` to define the TOC formatting, as @PeterWilson suggests.

Comment: Close voters: the OP has clarified the package they are using, so the question is no longer unclear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @dexteritas You're asking for a MWE for a question that already has an answer. While a MWE certainly helps in the general case, since this is simply a case of a package option, no MWE is really needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `arsclassica` package loads the `classicthesis` package, which has a `dottedtoc` option to right align the TOC entries:

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]